# "not authorized" error when cloning from JGit, working with Git Bash

Tags: azure, authentication, clone, jgit

Here is my code for cloning:

```
cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(user, pswd);

Git clone = Git.cloneRepository()
           .setURI("http://machine_name/repo_name")
           .setDirectory("new_dir")
           .setCloneAllBranches( true )
           .setCredentialsProvider(cp)
           .call();
```

I am getting "http://machine_name/repo_name: not authorized" from the machine that has repos under AZURE.
When I try from Git Bash "git clone http://user:pswd@machine_name/repo_name new_dir" it works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using the URL which includes username and password with JGit? Maybe omitting the credentials provider?

Comment: When I try to use the URL which includes username and password I get the following error: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered

Comment: Does it help to set a dummy credentials provider? or to repeat user name and password from the URL in the credentials provider?

Comment: When using dummy/repeat credentials provider - back to original "not authorized". I also noticed that when I try it from linux box with "git clone" command and it prompts me for user/password - it works, but when I make user/password part of the URL - it gives me "not authorized" ( same command works from Git Bash windows. ) Based on the logs the credentials in all cases where it fails don't make it through...

Comment: Is that true that Azure requires SSH authentication?

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with Azure from JGTI without getting ssh protocol involved?

Answer (score 0):

today i meet the same question.the key is that your account and password.if you use the ALM as your git service. you need to create "personal token" in the security center,and use the token name as the account and use the token as the password.